# Why are NTFS partitions displayed but NTFS-3G partitions are not?

Tags: mount, fstab, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I'm running Debian Wheezy and have three internal `ntfs` Windows partitions (main, boot, and recovery).  They are mounted via entries in `fstab`.  The filesystem specified for the boot and recovery partitions is `ntfs`.  The main Windows partition is `ntfs-3g`.  I understand that, at least several years ago, `ntfs-3g` was needed for write capability.

However, write capability appears to not be the only implication.  The Windows boot partition shows up in the `Dolphin` Places panel, but the main Windows partition does not.  If I right-click on a file to save it, the boot partition shows up in the context menu drives list but the main Windows partition does not.  I can navigate to the mount directory and access it from there but that is not very handy.

I had assumed this behavior is related the the filesystem designation in `fstab`.  Until the `fstab` entries were created, the `ntfs` partitions were not recognized, so I assume none are being handled by `udisks` or `udev`.  The only substantive difference in the `fstab`entries is the filesystem spec.

However, as a test, I unmounted the Windows partition and remounted it with a `mount` command specifying `ntfs` as the filesystem.  I verified that it is mounted, but the partition still is not displayed in either place.  So the `ntfs-3g` designation was not the problem.

I previously used Mint 17, which came pre-configured to recognize `ntfs` partitions and did not exhibit this problem.  So the issue is not hardware-related (as in some type of corruption).

Why is the boot partition displayed but not the main partition?  Could it be that the boot and recovery partitions are not `FUSE` and Debian has problems with `FUSE`?  Any suggestion for a fix?